# How to call Firebase function in Swift when parameters changed?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

```
func handleOnlineUsersWithParameters(param1: Float, param2: Float) {

    databaseReference.child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

          if snapshot.value > param1 && snapshot.value < param2 {
                // DO SOMETHING
          }
    })
}
```

As you can see in this function, my operations change depending on param1 and param2.
My question is; param1 and param2 is always changeable by user. Is it wrong if I call this function when parameters are changed constantly? What are the alternatives for Firebase handling? Is it going to be slow while I'm calling this all the time?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That would not be correct, because you would be observing the same child multiple times. For what I see, I would suggest something like:

```
class FirebaseObserver {
    var param1: Float = 0.0
    var param2: Float = 0.0

    let databaseReference: FIRReference // I don't remember the type of that, sorry!
    init() { addObserver() }
    deinit { // Remove observer }

    func addObserver() {
        databaseReference.child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
            checkAddedChild(value: snapshot.value)
        }
    }

    func checkAddedChild(value: Float) {
        if value > param1, value < param2 {
            // DO SOMETHING
        }
     }
```

And from your main class:

```
class MainClass {
    let firebaseObserver = FirebaseObserver()

    func somethingThatChangedParams() {
        firebaseObserver.param1 = 10
        firebaseObserver.param2 = 20
    }
```

So, you will be having only one observer and it will check the added child, with the values you can update anytime.